# Add curl command to function for bash profile

Tags: bash

How do I add this command as an alias or function to my bash_profile?

```
curl -X GET -H "x-api-key:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "Content-Type: application/json"  https://xxxxxxx.amazonaws.com/api/ | jq
```

I tried this:

```
my-func () { curl -X GET -H "x-api-key:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "Content-Type: application/json"  https://xxxxxxx.amazonaws.com/api/ | jq; }
```

I get the following error when trying to add as an alias or use in a function.

```
-bash: `${
  "message": "Missing Authentication Token"
}': not a valid identifier
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file ".bashrc" of your user :

- /root/.bashrc for root user
- /home/user/.bashrc for user

You have examples of alias in it :)

Comment: Checked on my Mac and I don't see this.